# Setting java path in .bat file

Tags: java, windows-8, environment-variables

On Windows 8, I've got a bat file with the following contents:

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39
echo setting PATH
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin;%PATH%
echo Display java version
java -version
```

which I'm trying to use to switch java versions. When I run the .bat file, it outputs the version as 1.6.0_39, but doesn't actually switch versions.  Instead, I've had to manually change the path variable every time I want to use a different version.
Is there something wrong with the way that I'm setting the path? When I look at the path env variable after I've run this, it doesn't look like it's changed, and you'd think that it would be fairly visible...

Current version:

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09"
echo Display java version
java -version
```

with %JAVA_HOME%\bin; at the front of my path variable.
Doesn't seem to be looking at %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: [Use `setx` instead of `set`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: is the syntax for setx the same? I tried this and got an error: "Default option is not allowed more that '2' times"

Comment: Figured out how to get setx to work right, but now it's not finding java... I added %JAVA_HOME%\bin; to the beginning of my path, deleted the setx path from my .bat, and it doesn't seem to be using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SET` statement sets an environment variable for the *current process* only.

Set the the global (default) value of an environment variable, use `setx`.

Note that even `setx` will not affect existing processes, so you will only notice the change in a new command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

SETX is often not supported. You can also change the registry setting. See [>> this post](https://superuser.com/questions/135056/set-permanent-environmental-variable-in-windows-xp)

Comment: I figured out how to get setx to work, but now it can't seem to find java, even though I've got %JAVA_HOME%/bin in my path.